# PayPal ipnNotificationUrl

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

When a customer clicks on my Pay Now button I already have the ID of the transaction. So I do it like this;

`<input type="hidden" name="return" value="successurl.php?id=1234567890">`
`<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="failureurl.php?id=1234567890">`
`<input type="hidden" name="ipnNotificationUrl" value="ipnurl.php?id=1234567890">`

The first two lines work OK, but PayPal doesn't call the ipn url on the third line. Anyone knows why? (Unfortanatly no answer from PayPal :( )

Answer (score 1):

The field name for that is `notify_url`, not `ipnNotificationUrl`.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="ipnurl.php?id=1234567890">` Doesn't work either!

Comment: You can verify that notify_url is correct with [PayPal's standard variable doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).  If your IPN script isn't doing what you expect then you need to [troubleshoot accordingly](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).

Comment: It's easy to check that the php code in ipnurl.php works. Except for the HTML dump (in success.php), it's got the same code as successurl.php. When any of these modules are called upon, a dump email is sent to me, so therefore I know PayPal doesn't call ipnurl.php but does move the user to successurl.php after a successful payment. I do NOT include the ppipn.php module, but I use only `$_GET['id']`, cause that's the only information I need.

Comment: Sorry! The module I referred to (from github.com) isn't called ppipn.php but **PaypalIPN.php**

Comment: IPN does not use GET, it uses POST.  It also doesn't have anything to do with a return URL / success page.  That would be PDT.

Comment: I use GET in the **return** URL and the **cancel_return** URL (check my code). Both work just fine. For certain reasons I tried to do the same with **notify_url**. It didn't work. What a shame. I guess I have to use POST variables in **notify_url**.

Comment: Reeturn and Cancel are completely separate from Notify and can be configured for either GET or POST. Notify requires POST as its a simple server-to-server communication that happens outside the browser.

Comment: While trying all sorts of things I found out you **can** use GET in Notify, but there's no reason to use GET, since you **have** to use POST anyhow, and in POST you will find all the info you need. - Thanks for your help!